# Add company branding to Vimeo password screen

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-player

Is it possible to add a logo or custom theme/css to password screen? we are sharing these private video links with our clients and we want to show our companies branding on the password screen.

[password screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cr2Rk.png)